# Issue Converting Between Watts and ft*lbf/s

Tags: fluid-dynamics, unit-of-measure

I am solving a mechanical engineering fluids problem and I've run into a weird unit conversion issue:

The density of water is $1000\ \mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{m}^3$. This is $62.43\ \mathrm{lb}/\mathrm{ft}^3$ [calculation on wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1000+kg%2Fm%5E3+to+lb%2Fft%5E3)

The flow rate is $1.5\ \mathrm{ft}^3/\mathrm{s}$ which is $0.0425\ \mathrm{m}^3/\mathrm{s}$ [calculation on wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.5+ft%5E3%2Fs+to+m%5E3%2Fs)

The diameter of the nozzle is 4 inches which is $\pi\cdot (4/2)^2 = 12.6\ \mathrm{in}^2$ which is $0.008107\ \mathrm{m}^2$ or $0.08727\ \mathrm{ft}^2$.

When I take all of the quantities in meters, kg, and seconds, I get 0.7832 horsepower [calculation on wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1000*0.0425*%28-%280.0425%2F0.008107%29%5E2%2F2%29+Watts+to+horsepower)

When I take all of the quantities in feet, pounds, and seconds, I get 25.15 horsepower [calculation on wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-1.5*62.43*%28-+%281.5%2F0.08727%29%5E2%2F2%29%29+lbf*ft%2Fs+to+horsepower).

This makes no sense to me... Please help

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The issue is that foot pounds of force aren't the same as lb*ft^2/s^3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)